# Documenting callback parameters using Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, callback, documentation, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

How can you document names and descriptions of callback parameters using the Google Closure Compiler?

After reading [this answer on documenting callbacks with JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3171454/2407870), I tried using `@callback` and `@typedef` and `@name` tags, but ran into issues with each one.

With `@callback`, Closure gives an "illegal use of unknown JSDoc tag" warning:

```
/**
 * @callback EndDrawCallback
 * @param {string} action - either "keep", "discard", or "cancel"
 * @param {boolean} saveChanges - whether to mark changes as saved
**/
```

With `@typedef`, it gives a "type annotation incompatible with other annotations":

```
/**
 * @typedef {function(string,boolean)}
 * @param {string} action ...
 * @param {boolean} saveChanges ...
**/
var EndDrawCallback;
```

Using `@name`, it gives a warning "Unknown type EndDrawCallback" when trying to use the callback name as a type:

```
/**
 * @name EndDrawCallback
 * @function
 * @param {string} action ...
 * @param {boolean} saveChanges ...
**/
```

The only alternatives I can see are

(a) to give up and write documentation after the callback param without using tags, or
(b) to restructure the code to pass a single object into the callback, with named properties.

In this case at least, (b) is not an option. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Are you just wanting the jsdoc for documentation generation? Or do you want to use them for closure compiler type checking?

Comment: Type checking would be a bonus, but mostly I just want to get the documentation in there with as little repetition as possible. The main source of repetition here is doing `function(string,boolean)` and then `@param {string} ...`. Having it in two different comment blocks means it might easily diverge, so it would be great to define the callback type once and then just reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--extra_annotation_name` flag to specify JSDoc tags that the compiler does not recognize. Since the compiler recognizes and uses `@typedef`, you would need to utilize either the `@callback` or `@name` annotations.

Comment: This is a good suggestion for getting rid of the warnings, thanks.