# How do I document complex callback requirement in JSDoc while keeping JSDoc's Generator, Closure-Compiler and VS-Code happy

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

Please consider following jsdoc-ed callback

```
/**
 * @callback create_stub
 * @param {Object} co_obj 
 * An object containing method to create the stub.
 * @param {string} method_name
 * A member function name of co_obj.
 * ...
 */
```

The above will work for JSDoc's documentation generator. Will be documented as typedef.

For Closure-Compiler however, it does not seem to work well. By "not work well" I mean:
Even if it works, compiler will not be able to perform type checks I think because -
the only solution for closure-compiler to use callback tag is just to remove the warning(See [Documenting callback parameters using Google Closure Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899452)).
Note: that solution did not work for me. I still get "Unknown type create_stub" warning.

For VS-Code: Intellisense will not work. See "https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7515".
Now, with @typedef - everyone will be happy except that "I can not document parameters".

And, with @name (see [Best way to document anonymous objects and functions with jsdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171454)) - generator will document callback as method rather than a typedef, closure-compiler seem to have no effects.

Finally, I would like to say that I am currently using my own workaround that uses both @name and @typedef to keep Generator, CC and VS-Code happy. Sample:

```
/**
 * @function
 * @name Klass.typedefs.create_stub
 * @param {Object} co_obj 
 * An object containing method to create the stub.
 * @param {string} method_name
 * A member function name of co_obj.
 * ...
 *//**
 * @private
 * @typedef {function(Object, string)} Klass.typedefs.create_stub
 */
 Klass.typedefs.create_stub; // this line is needed for Closure-Compiler compatibility
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you actually use the `create_stub` to annotate a callback?  Or do you not do that, and your workaround is only for documentation purposes?

Comment: @CarlG `@param {Klass.typedefs.create_stub} cb`