# Inquiry to write function to javascript Object JSDoc property

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I need to put a function in a javascript object, how do I add a JSDoc comment in this case?

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} testObj
 * @property {!String} testName - testName
 * @property {?Function} [testFunction=null] - testFunction
 *
 */
var testObj = {
    testName:null,
    testFunction:null
}
```

In this form, null is the default value for the function, so it is expressed like this.

I just want to ask if it is enough to write only the `@property {?Function}` and write the parameter in the Object part, or if there is another way.

In the testFunction above, I want to show in JSDoc that a function with parameters `{Number} a, {number} b, {Object} c` is put in. If there is a way, I would appreciate it if you let me know.
And I also want to express that this function returns a `String`.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/17811177/1354378

Comment: ``@Even`` So, does it mean that `@callback` should be used for elements that can contain null or Function in Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@function` to define the function first, and then use the name of the function anywhere you need it, example:

```js
/**
 * A test function
 *
 * @function testFunction
 * @param  {number} a Number a
 * @param  {number} b Number b
 * @param  {Object} c Object c
 * @returns {string} Returns a string
 */

/**
 * A test Object
 *
 * @typedef {Object} testObj
 * @property {!string} testName The Test Name
 * @property {?testFunction} testFunction The Test Function
 */
const testObj = {
  testName: null,
  testFunction: null,
}
```

Just tested it with [jsdoc](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc) and the documentation is generated correctly with the link in the testFunction property.

[image]